Single IP timeout from single machine - local network stack messed up?
We have one Windows 10 laptop that times out connecting to a certain website on port 80 and 443.
A second webserver by the same company in the same subnet is reachable.

ping and tracert to this IP work just fine (!)
All other machines and phones can connect to this website just fine.
I doesn't matter which network the machine is using - I have tried both the local network as well as connecting to the net via a phone hotspot, i.e. a completely independent connection. I also tried cabled connection to the router instead of WLAN.
I would rule out local AV/firewall, because if I block that IP explicitly in the AV-firewall, curl does not report "Timed out" but does report "Bad access". (also, temporarily disabling the firewall completely doesn't change anything.)
wget, curl, Firefox, Edge run into the same timeout issue.
It's as if for this single machine, the remote IP doesn't listen on any port (80, 443 that is)
This website used to work from this machine just fine. No infrastructure changes were made since last time. (And they wouldn't matter, I think, because it doesn't work via the phone hotspot either.)

It's as if the network stack on this machine times out only on this specific address.
Any persistent Windows network settings that could mess up a specific ipv4 address?
The "obvious" next step (after all that are listed here so far) would be to uninstall AV/firewall and see whether the problem persists, but this is so meh! :-)
route seems fine, no proxy configured. Firewall rules are fine and it does not work even with disabled firewall.
Wireshark doesn't really help: All it shows is that the TCP SYN ist sent and no answer received whatsoever.
For completeness sake, here's some output:
Wireshark:
Frame 56: 62 bytes on wire (496 bits), 62 bytes captured (496 bits) on interface \Device\NPF_{48C9292D-BCCF-4C39-8CEA-A04B268E6885}, id 0
Ethernet II, Src: WistronInfoc_9b:ec:5d (20:6a:8a:9b:ec:5d), Dst: AVMAudiovisu_f1:25:55 (2c:3a:fd:f1:25:55)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.178.41, Dst: 192.124.249.153
    0100 .... = Version: 4
    .... 0101 = Header Length: 20 bytes (5)
    Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP: CS0, ECN: Not-ECT)
    Total Length: 48
    Identification: 0x928e (37518)
    010. .... = Flags: 0x2, Don't fragment
    ...0 0000 0000 0000 = Fragment Offset: 0
    Time to Live: 128
    Protocol: TCP (6)
    Header Checksum: 0x3b51 [validation disabled]
    [Header checksum status: Unverified]
    Source Address: 192.168.178.41
    Destination Address: 192.124.249.153
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 63406, Dst Port: 80, Seq: 0, Len: 0
    Source Port: 63406
    Destination Port: 80
    [Stream index: 2]
    [Conversation completeness: Incomplete, SYN_SENT (1)]
    [TCP Segment Len: 0]
    Sequence Number: 0    (relative sequence number)
    Sequence Number (raw): 2802425601
    [Next Sequence Number: 1    (relative sequence number)]
    Acknowledgment Number: 0
    Acknowledgment number (raw): 0
    0111 .... = Header Length: 28 bytes (7)
    Flags: 0x002 (SYN)
    Window: 64240
    [Calculated window size: 64240]
    Checksum: 0x1d3c [unverified]
    [Checksum Status: Unverified]
    Urgent Pointer: 0
    Options: (8 bytes), Maximum segment size, No-Operation (NOP), No-Operation (NOP), SACK permitted
    [Timestamps]


tracert*works:
tracert df.eu

Routenverfolgung zu df.eu [192.124.249.153]
über maximal 30 Hops:

  1     2 ms     3 ms     2 ms  fritz.box [192.168.178.1]
  2    11 ms    12 ms    10 ms  ...
  3    26 ms    20 ms    26 ms  ...
  4    31 ms    20 ms    32 ms  at-vie03c-rc01.as8412.net [217.25.122.57]
  5    19 ms    19 ms    19 ms  80.157.205.57
  6    19 ms    21 ms    19 ms  vie-sb5-i.VIE.AT.NET.DTAG.DE [217.239.40.122]
  7    23 ms    18 ms    21 ms  62.157.250.107
  8    35 ms   579 ms    46 ms  ae32.cr1-fra6.ip4.gtt.net [213.200.115.161]
  9    35 ms    29 ms    30 ms  ip4.gtt.net [87.119.92.2]
 10    32 ms    30 ms    30 ms  cloudproxy10153.sucuri.net [192.124.249.153]


tracert admin.df.eu

Routenverfolgung zu admin.df.eu [192.124.249.168]
über maximal 30 Hops:

  1     2 ms     1 ms     1 ms  fritz.box [192.168.178.1]
  2   293 ms    10 ms    10 ms  ...
  3   376 ms    21 ms    17 ms  ...
  4    17 ms    16 ms    17 ms  at-vie09c-rc01.as8412.net [217.25.122.61]
  5    19 ms    18 ms    19 ms  80.157.205.225
  6   301 ms    16 ms    21 ms  62.157.250.107
  7    33 ms    28 ms    28 ms  ae32.cr1-fra6.ip4.gtt.net [213.200.115.161]
  8    29 ms    29 ms    28 ms  ip4.gtt.net [87.119.92.2]
  9   230 ms    29 ms    30 ms  cloudproxy10168.sucuri.net [192.124.249.168]


Curl Test runs:
# Doesn't work / timeout:
PS C:\Local\curl\bin> .\curl.exe http://www.df.eu -v
* Host www.df.eu:80 was resolved.
* IPv6: (none)
* IPv4: 192.124.249.153
*   Trying 192.124.249.153:80...
* connect to 192.124.249.153 port 80 from 0.0.0.0 port 51269 failed: Timed out
* Failed to connect to www.df.eu port 80 after 21041 ms: Couldn't connect to server
* Closing connection
curl: (28) Failed to connect to www.df.eu port 80 after 21041 ms: Couldn't connect to server

# this "nearby" website works:
PS C:\Local\curl\bin> .\curl.exe http://admin.df.eu -v
* Host admin.df.eu:80 was resolved.
* IPv6: (none)
* IPv4: 192.124.249.168
*   Trying 192.124.249.168:80...
* Connected to admin.df.eu (192.124.249.168) port 80
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: admin.df.eu
> User-Agent: curl/8.8.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Request completely sent off
...


# If website manually blocked by AV-firewall I get:
    * connect to 192.124.249.153 port 80 from 0.0.0.0 port 51204 failed: Bad access
# immediately.

The local routing table seems fine:
IPv4-Routentabelle
===========================================================================
Aktive Routen:
     Netzwerkziel    Netzwerkmaske          Gateway    Schnittstelle Metrik
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.178.1   192.168.178.69     50
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    331
    192.168.178.0    255.255.255.0   Auf Verbindung    192.168.178.69    306
   192.168.178.69  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung    192.168.178.69    306
  192.168.178.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung    192.168.178.69    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0   Auf Verbindung    192.168.178.69    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung    192.168.178.69    306
===========================================================================
Ständige Routen:
  Keine


Should I try Wireshark. Yes, you should.

@GregAskew - well Wireshark didn't really help so far ... it seems to indicate that the SYN is sent, but nothing received back. +shrug+

Where are you running Wireshark -- on the origin machine or the destination machine? It you see the SYN packets show up at the destination but you don't see a reply, the problem is clearly with the local configuration on the destination machine. If you're running wireshark on the origin machine, you're not really going to learn anything. You already know you can't establish a connection.

@larsks - Since I don't own the destination, I can't run it there. I have now also done an eth trace on my router - what I see there is that the SYN packet goes out, but no ACK comes back. But only for this one machine. Other devices behind the same NAT work just fine. The wireshark frames look "identical" to me.

RIght, but you already knew that. Running wireshark on "your" side of the connection isn't going to tell you anything useful (other than that the problem appears to be somewhere on the "other" side of your router).

@larks - wrt the router: No, I did not already know that the packet made it to my router; so wireshark helped here. It just doesn't solve the riddle :-)
